# How to add a key listener for a view in other plugins?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, keylistener, e4

There is a plugin with a view (TreeViewer) that was injected after created. In another plugin, I want to add a key listener to this TreeViewer. But I down't know where to write the register. I tried in an add-on or Activator.java but failed. Please give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: If the plugin does not provide a way to get the viewer you can't do this.

Comment: Yes, I can access to the viewer. I can add the listener in my own plugin handler event. But if I add in others (add-on), the viewer is null (not yet created) so I cannot register the key listener.

Comment: There is a solution using EventBroker in that the plugin of the viewer will send out the key pressed and then I will listen for this topic with the key data.

Comment: Event broker makes sense.